# NativeScript Angular forms

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, nativescript

I want to change the ActionBar of my app on the Login-page when the user touches the first Textfield.
There are only two Textfields (Email and password)

I thought of triggering this behavior template-driven with `ngModel` but it just doesn't work as wanted.
So I tried doing it reactive as I am doing it for checking the validity before sumbitting the login-credentials. But neither Did I find a way to make that work.

My Idea was to use the property `touched` of the Textfields and if it is `true` than I wanted to simply display a different Actionbar.
My Problem is that I didn't find a way to get boolean of the property `touched` of my Textfields inside my TypeScript code.

here is my Code so far:

**anmeldung.component.html:**

```
<ns-action-bar title="Anmeldung"  [showImage]="true" ></ns-action-bar>
<StackLayout  class="form" [formGroup]="form">
    <StackLayout *ngIf="!isLoading" class="input-field">
        <TextField
         class="input"
         hint="Enter E-Mail"
         keyboardType="email"
          required
         [autocorrect]="false"
         autocapitalizationType="none"
         formControlName="email"
         #emailEl
        ></TextField>
        <Label class="label" *ngIf="!emailControlIsValid" text="Please enter a valid E-Mail"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *ngIf="!isLoading" class="input-field">
        <TextField
          class="input"
          hint="Enter Passwort"
          [secure]="true"
           required
           returnKeyType="go"
           [autocorrect]="false"
          formControlName="password"
          (returnPress)="onSubmit()"
          #passwordEl
        ></TextField>
        <Label class="label" *ngIf="!passwordControlIsValid" text="Please enter a valid Password"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <Button class="button"
        text="Login"
        (tap)="onSubmit()"
        *ngIf="!isLoading"
    ></Button><!--[isEnabled]="form.valid"-->
    <FlexboxLayout justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" *ngIf="isLoading">
            <ActivityIndicator [busy]="isLoading"></ActivityIndicator>
    </FlexboxLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

**anmeldung.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { TextField } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/text-field';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../authentication.service';
import { SystemService } from '../system/liste-system/system.service';
import { System } from '../system/liste-system/system.model';
import { alert } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs';
//import { PushNotificationHandler } from "../pushNotification/push-notification-handler.service"
import { UIService } from '../shared/ui.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ns-anmeldung',
  templateUrl: './anmeldung.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./anmeldung.component.scss'],
  moduleId: module.id,
})
export class AnmeldungComponent implements OnInit {
    isLoading = true;
    form: FormGroup;
    emailControlIsValid = true;
    passwordControlIsValid = true;
    @ViewChild('passwordEl', {static: false})passwordEl: ElementRef<TextField>;
    @ViewChild('emailEl', {static: false})emailEl: ElementRef<TextField>;
    constructor(
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private systemService: SystemService,
        private router: RouterExtensions,
        private uiService: UIService){}
        //private pushNoteHandler: PushNotificationHandler){}
        
    ngOnInit() {
        this.uiService.sideDrawerSwipe = false;
        this.authenticationService.autologin().subscribe(success =>{
            if(success){
                this.router.navigate(['/monitorliste'],{clearHistory: true});
            }else{
                // clear system settings => be careful that everything gets deleted for later changes
            }
            setTimeout(() => {this.isLoading = false;}, 1000);
        });

        this.form=new FormGroup({
            email: new FormControl(null, {updateOn: 'blur', validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]}),
            password: new FormControl(null, {updateOn: 'blur',validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]})
        });
        this.form.get('email').statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
            this.emailControlIsValid = status== 'VALID';
        });
        this.form.get('password').statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
            this.passwordControlIsValid = status== 'VALID';
        });
    }

    onSubmit(){
        this.emailEl.nativeElement.focus();
        this.passwordEl.nativeElement.focus();
        this.passwordEl.nativeElement.dismissSoftInput();
        if(!this.form.valid){
            return;
        }
        const email = this.form.get('email').value;
        const password = this.form.get('password').value;
        this.form.reset();
        this.emailControlIsValid= true;
        this.passwordControlIsValid=true;
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.authenticationService.get_systeme(email, password).subscribe(async (res : System[])=>{
            await this.systemService.createNewSystem(res);
             //pushnotehandler update appsettings => resub to systems
            //this.pushNoteHandler.resubAllTopics();

            this.router.navigate(['/system'], {clearHistory: true, transition: {name: 'slideLeft'}});
            this.isLoading = false;
            },
            err =>{
                alert(err);
                this.isLoading = false;
        });;
    }

    onDone(){
        this.emailEl.nativeElement.focus();
        this.passwordEl.nativeElement.focus();
        this.passwordEl.nativeElement.dismissSoftInput();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#formcontrol) Class have touched property we can use that to check whether the input field is touched or not.

**Try this:**

```
this.form.get('email').tocuhed
```

Comment: How to use thisin the actionbar? I thought about doing this with `*ngIf`

Comment: you can use this condition directly on template like ngIf="form.get('email').tocuhed"" somethink like this. or you define getter in component and use that getter to ngIf